# how to draw path between two location in using map box?

Tags: flutter, mapbox, flutter-dependencies

I want to draw path between two points. I am using [flutter_map 0.10.1+1](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map) package to include map.

I am getting points between two locations using map box api. When I draw Polyline using that points it draws straight line, instead of drawing line on road.

For example I am getting following points when I try to get points between two location:

```
LatLng(latitude:21.202751, longitude:72.838807)
LatLng(latitude:21.198725, longitude:72.836119)
LatLng(latitude:21.196459, longitude:72.83742)
LatLng(latitude:21.195418, longitude:72.836605)
LatLng(latitude:21.195194, longitude:72.836577)
LatLng(latitude:21.189253, longitude:72.832431)
LatLng(latitude:21.186454, longitude:72.829726)
```

checkout following image how I am able to draw line.

[image]

Comment: You need to use some kind of API to get path that follows roads, that's not a task that is solved with 2 lines of code. Also, there is no free API for that AFAIK

Comment: @DimaRostopira I don't found any direct way, so i tried this way. can you share any direct way for mapbox as there is for googlemap ?

Comment: I forgot to update but I found an API in Mapbox in which you can pass the above-received points and it will provide a route with detailed points. Basically, you need to use two APIs to get the final route.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the polylines mode type in the package you use.

```
 GoogleMapPolyline googleMapPolyline =
      new GoogleMapPolyline(apiKey: "yourkeyhere");

googleMapPolyline.getCoordinatesWithLocation(
        origin: LatLng(40.6782, -73.9442),
        destination: LatLng(40.6944, -73.9212),
         mode: RouteMode.driving);--->You need to set the mode type
```

Comment: i did not found any option like that in flutte_map plugin. main point is that i am using mapbox not googlMap, so i have choose package accordingly. can you named any package that provide that option ?

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/google_map_polyline/ add  this packages for pollyines

Comment: see this link https://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/examples/show-directions-on-a-map/